# occasional error >>> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a inventory control system and I want to edit user who is assigned to stores. A user can be assigned to one or more stores. I am using multiple select option. My problem here is, in edit user page, I want to show user assigned to stores as selected. But when I am going to do that I got this error(***Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 194*** ) only when user is not assigned for all stores.

e.g.- say there is 3 stores called A, B and C

1.)if I am going to edit user who assigned to all three stores I won't get any error.
2.)If I am going to edit user who assigned to 2 stores I will get above error twice.
3.)If I am going to edit user who assigned to only one store I will get above error only once.

Please help me to correct this.

this is my code

```
$emp_id = $_GET['emp_id'];
$result1 = mysql_query("Select *
                            from members
                            JOIN store_employee on members.emp_id = store_employee.emp_id
                            JOIN stores on store_employee.store_id = stores.store_id
                            where members.emp_id=$emp_id")
               or die(mysql_error());
$query="SELECT * FROM stores";
        $dropdown = "<select name='store_id[]' multiple='multiple'  style='height:80px;' size='5' id='store'>";
        $result2 = mysql_query ($query);
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
        {

  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row2['store_id']}'";

            foreach(mysql_fetch_array($result1) as $row1)     //this is line 194
              {
                 if(($row1['store_id'])==($row2['store_id']))
                  {
                      $dropdown .=" selected='selected'";
                  }

             }
  $dropdown .= ">{$row2['store_name']}</option>";
        }
        $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
        echo $dropdown;
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Thanku for u reply.  This is a university mini project i have used mysql_ functions until now and i am so urgent to finish this before dead line so cant go for mysqli or PDO sadly no time at all

Comment: That's no excuse. That "no time" will come back and bite you in the long run. I'm just saying. **[There's no excuse for bad code!](http://vimeo.com/13439458)**

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array` is most definitely not used in that manner, especially considering that it's, you know, a function and not an array, even if it returns one.

What you want is something like this:

```
$user_stores;
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $user_stores[] = $rows;
}
while ($rows2...
    //...
    foreach ($user_stores as $row1) {
        //...
    }
}
```

If you do the `mysql_fetch_array` inside the other `mysql_fetch_array`, you can end up passing a value in `$row1` which could match a later entry in `$row2`. This should help fix the issue.

Also, `mysql_*` functions are soon to be deprecated. Do not use them in new code (and really, you should look into removing them from *all* code). Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. If you're a lazy bum (like me), you can look into using `mysqli`'s procedural style, which is almost identical to the original `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: edit>>>>>Thanku for ur reply. I have tried hile ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
instead of foreach. but then it doesnt show all selected items.It shows only ane selected item. dats y i use this way to get results. This is a university mini project i have used mysql_ functions until now and i am so urgent to finish this before dead line so cant go for mysqli or PDO sadly no time at all